# How to implement a UIPageIndicator like a line

Tags: ios, swift4, uipagecontrol

I want to implement a page indicator like a line.
[image]

Comment: use UIlabel or UIview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must create UIControl like line or use 
from Github ready codes:

- https://github.com/leonx98/LXPageControl
- https://github.com/ChiliLabs/CHIPageControl